# How to duplicate the list value and append back to the same list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

For example if:

```
List = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

I want like this:

```
List = [1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5]
```

Comment: What if `List = [3, 1, 4, "allo", 42, False, None]` ?

Comment: [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2449077/1324033) - Put effort into your question(s) before posting.

Comment: @Sayse it's sometimes difficult to find duplicates (look at all the answers below). Just vote to close (I followed)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre - Thats true, but when I could find a duplicate with a [single google search for "python duplicate list"](https://imgur.com/a/2zYw2Ob), then I find it hard to believe the op put any effort in at all

Comment: Sure, Thanks for our suggestion.

Comment: the added value of high rep users like you is to help newcomers to find the duplicates. Let's imagine one second that the OP thinks that stackoverflow search works properly for instance :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre - I'll be doing a lot more helping when I get the dupe-hammer :) In the mean time, OP your posts like this are going to continue to get downvoted so I'd suggest reading [ask]

Comment: @Sayse I remember that the last 130 points are the toughest to get. Good luck :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `zip` the list with itself:

```
[i for t in zip(List, List) for i in t]
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
li = [1,2,3,4,5]

print(sorted(li+li))
```

Comment: This only provides the required output for this specific example. It will provide wrong output for any non-sorted input. Try `sorted(li + li, key=li.index`)

Comment: @DeepSpace that would really kill the efficiency, better to create a index map, so `sorted(li + li, key={x:i for i,x in enumerate(li)}.get)`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga or just `out = [] ;
    for i in li:
        li.append(i) ;
        li.append(i)`

simple O(n) with no sorting (O(nlogn))

Comment: @DeepSpace sure. Essentially, Jean-François Fabre's answer. But using a `key=li.index` will make it O(N**2 logN)

Comment: Thank you, **sorted(li + li, key=li.index)** this solution worked fine.

Comment: @venki don't use that key function, it kills the efficiency. n * logn is much better than quadratic time. use an index map.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Why O(N\*\*2 logN)? Pretty sure it's just O(N\*\*2).

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I don't understand what you mean, but I suspect you think the key function is called *during* the sorting for each comparison instead of just once for each element *before* the sorting?

Comment: @StefanPochmann ahhh right, actually, it isn't, it is only called once for each, so something like `N**2 + N* log N` => O(N**2) is what you mean? Yes I believe you are correct.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yes, that's what I think.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Lol... this actually gave me a really bad idea, and it does work: `sorted(a + a, key=lambda _, k=iter(list(range(len(a))) * 2): next(k))`.

Comment: @StefanPochmann that can actually be efficient, no need to materialize the list! just `sorted(a + a, key=iter(range(len(a)*2)).__next__)`,

Comment: Please improve my answer or post a new one after you conclude your best answer.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Nah, that doesn't work. For two big reasons.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Well, your second problem is that you create keys from 0 to 2n-1, which won't work for the sorting. But this works: `sorted(a + a, key=lambda _, k=itertools.cycle(range(len(a))): next(k))`. And [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59644433/1672429), too.

Comment: @StefanPochmann yes, damn, I see now. I actually prefer `sorted(a + a, key=lambda _, k=itertools.chain(*[range(len(a))]*2): next(k))`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga You prefer it over my original or over my `cycle` version? (not sure you saw the latter, as I ninja'd you)

Comment: @StefanPochmann over  both, because it requires the least amount of space, `cycle` materializes a list underneath the hood, I'm pretty sure

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Oh, right. It *could* recognize that it's a `range` and not materialize, but I doubt it does.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I think not just `range` but all immutable sequences would allow that optimization, and they [are](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#immutable-sequence-types) a thing, but I had a look at [the code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/itertoolsmodule.c#L942) and don't see any such optimization. It seems to indeed always store the elements in an internal list during the first iteration.

Answer (score 2):

you can use zip with chain(for flatten):

```
from itetools import chain

List = list(chain(*zip(List,List)))
print(List)
```

output:

```
[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5]
```

or you can use a `for` loop:

```
new_list = []
for n in List:
    new_list.extend([n, n])

List = new_list
print(new_list)
```

output:

```
[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this, if there is no notion of sorting:

```py
myList = [1,2,3,4,5]

for idx in range(0, len(myList)*2, 2):
  myList.insert(idx+1, myList[idx])

print(myList)
```

Comment: very inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `extend`. If you want to preserve the order.

```
l = [2,1,3,5,6]
res = []
for i in l:
    res.extend((i, i))
print(res)
```

output

```
[2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3, 5, 5, 6, 6]
```

---

```
res = []
l = [None, True, 5, 1, 8]
for i in l:
    res.extend((i, i))
print(res)
```

output

```
[None, None, True, True, 5, 5, 1, 1, 8, 8]
```